# IndexedDB to store audio

Tags: html, caching, indexeddb, offline-caching

Is it possible to use IndexedDB on a web page to store audio?

Currently trying out the Cache API, but looking for something that can be a little more persistent.

Comment: here are couple of [options](https://github.com/abudaan/heartbeat/wiki/Storing-audio-locally)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, as long as your files don't take more than 10% of the available space on the device's storage or 2GB whatever is smaller, you can store any binary file you wish in IndexedDB.

Answer (score -1):

IndexedDB is not recommended to be used for caching files.

For that purpose you can try to use the [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) instead ([canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)).