# Using indexedDB to Cache Audio Files Not Recommended?

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, browser-cache, indexeddb

I'd like to use indexedDB to store an audio file which I get from my CDN - to improve the users experience, and also do not put such heavy loads onto my CDN. Is this generally recommended for files like mp3? Are there any gotchas?

I've found a few tutorials on storing audio & image in indexedDb, but I also looked for answers on here before, [and here somebody says that indexedDB is not generally recommended to store audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850607/indexeddb-to-store-audio). - Is this true? Unfortunately, the person does not give any further explanation. So if this is true, I'd like to know *why*.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can store binary data in IndexedDB but need to be careful for platform limitations.

The main platform limit I know of is described in this [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/indexeddb-best-practices) article by a Google Engineer - the naive approach of storing a `Blob` type won't work on iOS - you need to convert to an `ArrayBuffer` using a pair of functions:

```
function blobToArrayBuffer(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    });
    reader.addEventListener('error', reject);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
}

function arrayBufferToBlob(buffer, type) {
  return new Blob([buffer], {type: type});
}
```

Many warnings against storage come from the (incorrect) assumption you have to convert data to base-64 encoded ASCII, which is slow and bloats the amount of spaces needed.